# Is there a good way to check return types when refactoring?

Tags: clojure, return-type

Currently when I'm refactoring in Clojure I tend to use the pattern:

```
(defn my-func [arg1 arg2]
  (assert (= demo.core.Record1 (class arg1) "Incorrect class for arg1: " (class arg1))
  (assert (= demo.core.Record1 (class arg2) "Incorrect class for arg2: " (class arg2))
  ...
```

That is, I find myself manually checking the return types in case a downstream part of the system modifies them to something I don't expect. (As in, if I refactor and get a stack-trace I don't expect, then I express my assumptions as invariants, and step forward from there).

In one sense, this is exactly the kind of invariant checking that [Bertrand Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Meyer) anticipated. (Author of [Object Oriented Software Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554), and proponent of the idea of [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)).

The challenge is that I don't find these out until run-time.  I would be nice to find these out at compile-time - by simply stating what the function expects.

Now *I know* Clojure is essentially a dynamic language. (Whilst Clojure has a 'compiler' of sorts, we should expect the application of values to a function to only come to realisation at run-time.)

I just want a good pattern to make refactoring easier. (ie see all the flow-on effects of changing an argument to a function, without seeing it break on the first call, then moving onto the next, then moving onto the next breakage.)

My question is: **Is there a good way to check return types when refactoring?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, only one of which is *"compile"* time:

**Tests**

As Clojure is a dynamic language, tests are absolutely essential. They are your safety net when refactoring. Even in statically typed languages tests are still of use.

**Pre and Post Conditions**

They allow you to verify your invariants by adding metadata to your functions such as in this example from [Michael Fogus' blog](http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/):

```
(defn constrained-fn [f x]
  {:pre  [(pos? x)]
   :post [(= % (* 2 x))]}
  (f x))

(constrained-fn #(* 2 %) 2)
;=> 4
(constrained-fn #(float (* 2 %)) 2)
;=> 4.0
(constrained-fn #(* 3 %) 2)
;=> java.lang.Exception: Assert failed: (= % (* 2 x)
```

**core.typed**

[core.typed](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed) is the only option in this list that will give you compile time checking. Your example would then be expressed like so:

```
(ann  my-func (Fn [Record1 Record1 -> ResultType]))
(defn my-func [arg1 arg2]
...)
```

This comes at the expense of running core.typed as a seperate action, possibly as part of your test suite.

And still on the realm of runtime validation/checking, there are even more options such as [bouncer](https://github.com/leonardoborges/bouncer) and [schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, prismatic/schema should be your choice.
https://github.com/plumatic/schema

```
(s/defn ^:always-validate my-func :- SomeResultClass
  [arg1 :- demo.core.Record1
   arg2 :- demo.core.Record1]
  ...)
```

you should just turn off all the validation before release, so it won't affect performance.

core.typed is nice, but as far as i remember, it enforces you to annotate all your code, while schema lets you only annotate critical parts.